# Why is the C++ syntax so complicated?

Tags: c++, python, syntax

I'm a novice at programming although I've been teaching myself Python for about a year and I studied C# some time ago.

This month I started C++ programming courses at my university and I just have to ask; "why is the C++ code so complicated?"

Writing "Hello world." in Python is as simple as "print 'Hello world.'" but in C++ it's:

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    cout << "Hello world.";
    return 0;
}
```

I know there is probably a good reason for all of this but, why...

- ... do you have to include the <iostream> everytime? Do you ever *not* need it?
- ... same question for the standard library, when do you not need std::*?
- ... is the "main" part a function? Do you ever call the main function? Why is it an integer? Why does C++ need to have a main function but Python doesn't?
- ... do you need "std::cout << "? Isn't that needlessly long and complicated compared to Python?
- ... do you need to return 0 even when you are never going to use it?

This is probably because I'm learning such basic C++ but every program I've made so far looks like this, so I have to retype the same code over and over again. Isn't that redundant? Couldn't the compiler just input this code itself, since it's always the same (i.e. afaik you always include <iostream>, std, int main, return 0)

Comment: Simple answer: C++ and Python are designed to solve different problems with different constraints. Different design goals get you different designs.

Comment: I am not sure what does the tag 'redundant-code' mean in this context. The task of main() in most non-trivial uses is not just to output to console. It is the entry-point for program executon. The return 0; is to the O.S. which launches the program and which *may* use the return value as status-reported from program execution. You may wish to read Dr. Stroustrup's FAQ first, before possibly incriminatng C++ of many other things apart from syntax @ http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq.html.

Comment: Seriously C++ may be the bee's knees, but I find it's code really complicated and tedius.

Comment: There are programs that don't need `<iostream>`. Believe me, when you see them, you're going to miss these simple programs that only include `<iostream>`.

Comment: This is why programmers should learn low-level languages FIRST, so they can appreciate what high-level languages do for them.

Comment: Baldur - C++ isn't only for writing console applications. You can write windowed apps, background services, embedded systems, games... basically anything. If you're writing something that's not a console app, you won't often need < iostream >.

Comment: @Eduardo Leon: When I was a beginning programmer I would have strongly disagreed with you. Now that I'm a computer science graduate and worked 2 years in industry, I strongly AGREE. You can't gain the low-level understanding by dabbling only in high-level languages.

Comment: If you are finding this complicated, then I wonder what happens when you start with templates..

Comment: @ Eduardo 
My friend told me to start learning assembly, because that would make my code less sloppy. I just didn't have the patience to learn it. I guess it's a bad idea in retrospect, or maybe I'll be more motivated to learn low-level languages now that I better know how they might be helpful.

I would also like to apologize for what many of you might see as a pointless question, but to in my defence it was annoying when you felt that 65,6% of the code I was writing was pointless.

Comment: @ Naveen

I don't find this complicated, I want to understand what I'm doing instead of writing it like a monkey. The teacher is currently reviewing things I learned ages ago but he never said anything about _why_ things are done this way. That's the reason I turned to SO.

Comment: Don't worry, I had the same questions when I moved from (the shame...) Visual Basic and Delphi to C++.

Comment: Visual Basic? My school used to teach us Visual Basic a long time ago and I hated every minute of it. Out of curiosity- does any company actually _use_ VB? I've only heard bad things about it.

Comment: Is there any reason to using VB over other programming languages?

Comment: One more: C++ is like 30 years, which is ancient in programming world.

Comment: Thanks god you havent seen the Java Hello World yet:P

Comment: I find it odd that Nobody responded that Python's syntax is simpler because it was designed that way - there is a hard constraint on the complexity of Python.

Comment: The short version: Python has a special magic word to display stuff on the screen. C++ doesn't, so you need to reference a library. That accounts for about half of the "boilerplate"; the other half is that programs start running from a function.

Comment: "Closed as not constructive" - pathetic.  This is one of the greatest and most potentially instructive questions I've seen on SO...

Comment: I now do Haskell.. thanks for the answers

Comment: @Iceland_jack Haskell ? You did the full Meme

Comment: This question predates all the stuff introduced in C++11, C++14, C++17, C++20, C++23, not even getting into all the stuff that was deprecated in favor of something even more generic! Like when cppreference mentions LegacyForwardIterator

Comment: I used to also believe beginner programmers should learn low-level programming, but now I believe they should understand the abstractions like data structures, references/pointers, asymptotic complexity, etc first. These are more important than the specifics of any language or architecture.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

C++ is a more low-level language that executes without the context of an interpreter. As such, it has many different design choices than does Python, because C++ has no environment which it can rely on to manage information like types and memory. C++ can be used to write an operating system kernel where there is no code running on the machine except for the program itself, which means that the language (some library facilities are not available for so-called freestanding implementations) must be self-contained. This is why C++ has no equivalent to Python's `eval`, nor a means of determining members, etc. of a class, nor other features that require an execution environment (or a massive overhead in the program itself instead of such an environment)

For your individual questions:

- do you have to include the `<iostream>` everytime? Do you ever not need it?

`#include <iostream>` is the directive that imports the `<iostream>` header into your program. `<iostream>` contains the standard input/output objects - in particular, `cout`. If you aren't using standard I/O objects (for instance, you use only file I/O, or your program uses a GUI library, or are writing an operating system kernel), you do not need `<iostream>`

- same question for the standard library, when do you not need std::*?

`std` is the namespace containing all of the standard library. `using namespace std;` is sort of like `from std import *`, whereas a `#include` directive is (in this regard) more like a barebones `import std` statement. (in actual fact, the mechanism is rather different, because C++ does not use `using namespace std;` to automatically lookup objects in `std`; the using-directive only imports the names into the global namespace.)

I'll note here that using-directives (`using namespace`) are frequently frowned upon in C++ code, as they import a lot of names and can cause name clashes. using-declarations (`using std::cout;`) are preferred when possible, as is limiting the scope of a using-directive (for instance, to one function or to one source file). Don't ever put `using namespace` in a header without good reason.

- is the "main" part a function? Do you ever call the main function? Why is it an integer? Why does C++ need to have a main function but Python doesn't?

`main` is the entry point to the program - where execution starts. In Python, the `__main__` module serves the same purpose. C++ does not execute code outside a defined function like Python does, so its entry point is a function rather than a module.

- do you need "std::cout << "? Isn't that needlessly long and complicated compared to Python?

`std::cout` is only needed if you don't import the `cout` name into the global namespace, either by a using-directive (`using namespace std;`) or by a using-declaration (`using std::cout`). In this regard, it is once again much like the distinction between Python's `import std` and `from std import *` or `from std import cout`.

The `<<` is an overloaded operator for standard stream objects. `cout << value` calls `cout`'s function to output `value`. Python needs no such extra code because `print` is built into the language; this does not make sense for C++, where there may not even be an operating system, much less an I/O library.

- do you need to return 0 even when you are never going to use it?

No. `main` (and no other function) has an implicit `return 0;` at the end. The return value of `main` (or, if the `exit` function is called, the value passed to it) is passed back to the operating system as the exit code. 0 indicates the program successfully executed - that it encountered no errors, etc. If an error is encountered, a non-zero value should be returned (or passed to `exit`).

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for that great and detailed response!

Comment: No problem :) I'm actually just learning Python myself, so it was a good test of my knowledge to be able to explain the other way back.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing this the wrong way. Do you think it would be a good idea to continue with C++ for a couple of months until I get a pretty solid foundation and then try studying low-level languages like assembly? Should high-level languages like Python be the last languages you learn?

Comment: I don't think there's necessarily anything wrong with starting from the top down. Assembly is frustrating to learn for a new programmer because it takes a lot of effort to do the simplest things (which is part of why it is such an effective way to learn coding). You don't even really need to understand assembly as much as you do computer architecture. I recommend a book like /Programming Language Pragmatics/, which explains how computers work, and so lets you understand all languages better. But as long as you keep an open mind (like asking this question rather than ranting) you'll do fine

Comment: "C++ does not execute code outside a defined function like Python does" - initialization of static variables can execute code

Comment: @M.M it can still be regarded as execution of code inside functions (constructors, even if default ones).

Comment: @M.M there's bound to be stuff like this when you have unmitigated all consuming complexity.

Comment: The overloaded bit shift operator for I/O is a weird design. C++23 introduced std::printf which avoids the operator overload and temporary std::string object, and replaces C++20 std::format. So yes they could've made it simpler.

Answer (score 14):

In response to your questions at the end of the post, it can be summed up with the philosophy of C++:

You don't pay for what you don't use.

You don't always need to use stdin or stdout (Windows/GUI apps?), nor will you always be using the STL, nor will everything you write necessarily use the standard main (winAPI) etc. As a previous poster said, C++ is lower level than Python. You will be exposed to more of the details, which **offers you more control over what you're doing.**

Answer (score 8):

> ... do you have to include the
>  everytime? Do you ever not
> need it?

You don't need it if you're not going to use `iostreams` in that module. In larger programs, few modules do any actual IO directly, and so few actually need to use `iostreams`.

Turning the question around: in python you need to import `sys` and/or `os` in most non-trivial programs. Why?

> ... same question for the standard
> library, when do you not need std::*?

You can have the using line or you can use the `std::` prefix. This is very similar to the choice python gives you of either saying `from sys import *` or `import sys` and then having to prefix things with `sys.`. In Python you have to say `sys.stdout`. Is `std::cout` really any worse?

> ... is the "main" part a function? Do
> you ever call the main function? Why
> is it an integer? Why does C++ need to
> have a main function but Python
> doesn't?

Yes, `main` is a function. Typically you wouldn't call it yourself. The name "main" is reserved for the entry-point of your program. It returns an integer because the value returned is used as the status code of your program. In Python you can use `sys.exit()` if you want to return a non-zero status code.

Python doesn't require a `main` function because in Python you can have code in a module that isn't in any function. This code is executed when you load the module. That said, the common convention in Python is to wrap code that you want to only run if the module is run as a program (rather than imported) in a block like:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Frequently this is used to call a `main` function:

```py
def main(argv):
  # program goes here

  return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
  sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Also, in Python you tell the interpreter which module is the "main" module when you run it. eg: `python foo.py`. In C++, like in C, the "main" module is (effectively) the one with a function called `main`. (If there are multiple modules with a `main` function, linking will fail.)

> ... do you need "std::cout << "? Isn't
> that needlessly long and complicated
> compared to Python?

The equivalent in Python is `sys.stdout.write(...)`. Python's print statement is a special-case short-hand that defaults to `sys.stdout`.

That said, many people do feel the `iostreams` convention of using bit-shifting operators for IO was a bad idea.

> ... do you need to return 0 even when
> you are never going to use it?

You aren't going to use it, but your program will. As mentioned earlier, the value you return is the status code of your program.

Aside: I actually do feel that C++ is over complicated, but not because of any of the points you mention. All of the differences you mention go away (in the sense that you need just as much complexity in Python) once you start writing non-trivial programs that have multiple modules and do more than just writing to stdout.

Comment: "in python you need to import sys and/or os in most non-trivial programs." not for most of the code I've written, which heavily uses libraries. Also C++23 introduced std::print instead of overloaded bitshift syntax so at least the C++ committee recognizes it's weird.

Comment: @qwr My point was that only very trivial Python programs don't import modules, and you seem to be agreeing with that point when you say "most of the code I've written, which heavily uses libraries". I also never mentioned the bitshift operators. As mentioned in the answer's last paragraph, I'm not a fan of C++, I just think the question misses the mark about what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 6):

You include `<iostream>` when you want to output things to the console. Since printing "Hello world" involves console output, you need `iostream`.

The `main` function is called by the operating system, basically. It gets called with the command-line arguments passed to the program. It returns an integer because the program must return an error code to the operating system (this is the standard way for determining if the last command was successful).

You can always use `printf("hello world");` instead of `std::cout << "hello world";` if you want to go C style. It's a bit quicker to write and lets you do formatted output.

You `return 0` from `main` to indicate that the program executed successfully.

The compiler does not automatically include all the standard libraries and use namespace `std` because sometimes name collisions can result between your code and library code that you may not actually need at all. You don't always need all the libraries. Likewise, sometimes you are using a different main routine (Windows development comes to mind with its own, different `WinMain` starting function). The compiler also does not automatically `return 0` because sometimes the program needs to indicate that it completed unsuccessfully.

Comment: For what it's worth, in plain C a program can call the `main()` function as well as the OS, though this is forbidden in C++. The only real purpose for this would be to generate everyone's favorite error.

Comment: And really, a stub put in by the compiler calls the `main()` function, but essentially, it's the OS that starts execution, and it has to start somewhere, some way.

Comment: This is a great answer, I just knew I wouldn't be able to keep up with C++ if I subconsciously think that what I'm doing is pointless.

Judging by the responses it does seem like _not_ using std and iostream is the EXCEPTION. Why not make a way to indicate that the user is not using std or iostream, opposed to indicating that the user is using them?

And I know that Python is a high-level language like Aziz pointed out (although I'm not too sure on the difference), but how can Python manage to have such a simple and beautiful syntax which does the same thing as that complicated C++ one?

Comment: I guess it's because C++ inherits greatly from C, an older, lower-level language. Programmers expect a great deal of control from C/C++, and part of that includes explicitly telling the compiler which headers to include and which namespaces to use. Python and scripting languages are a little more implicit and sacrifice some control for ease of development and maintenance.

Answer (score 6):

There are good reasons for all these things. C++ is a very broad language it is used for everything from small embedded systems to giant applications built by 100s of programmers. The use case of a guy building a small program to run on a desktop is by no means the only one. So sometimes you are building library components. In that case no main(). Sometimes you are working on a tiny system with no standard library. In that case no std. Sometimes you want to build a Unix tool that works with other Unix text tools and signals its completion status with an int returned from main().

In other words the things you complain about are boilerplate to you. But they are vital details that vary to other users of the language.

Answer (score 5):

This reminds me of [The Evolution of a Programmer](http://www.ariel.com.au/jokes/The_Evolution_of_a_Programmer.html). Some of the languages and technologies demonstrated are a bit dated now, but you should get the general idea. :)

Answer (score 5):

One of the reasons C++ is rather complicated is because it was designed to address problems that crop up in large programs. At the time C++ was created as AT&T, their biggest C program was about 10 million lines of code. At that scale, C doesn't function very well. C++ addresses many of the problems you get with that kind of program.

With that said, it's also possible to answer the original questions:

- You would `include <iostream>` where it's needed. If you've got 10.000 C++ files, it's quite common that less than 1000, sometimes less than 100 will produce user-visible output.
- A statement like `print "Hello, world"` assumes that there is a default output, but makes it hard to generalize. The `cout << "Hello, world"` form makes it explicit where the output goes, but the same form also allows `cerr << "Goodbye, world"` and `MyTmpFile << "Starting phase #" << i`
- The standard library is in the `std::` namespace. My 10.000 files will be in an additional 25 namespaces.
- `main` is an oddity in many ways, being the startup function.

Answer (score 3):

Baldur:

You don't always need `<iostream>`. The only things that you will always need are:

1. A `main` function (or a `WinMain`, if you're writing Win32 apps).
2. Variables, functions, operators, language constructs (`if`, `while`, etc.).
3. The ability to include functionality from libraries into your program.

Everything else is application-specific.

As other posters say, the return value of the `main` function is an error code<sup>1</sup>. If `main` returns 0, be happy: everything worked OK!

<sup>1</sup>This is useful when you write programs that "communicate" with other programs. The most simple way that a program can "tell" another whether it executed properly is using an error code.

Answer (score 2):

As people have said, the simple answer is that they're different languages, with different goals. To answer your specific questions...

> ... do you have to include the `<iostream>` everytime? Do you ever not need it?

`<iostream>` is one of the header files for iostreams, the part of the C++ standard library responsible for input/output; in this instance, you need it to gain access to `std::cout`. If you're not doing I/O operations in a source file, you don't need to include it -- for example, most files containing class definitions probably won't need `<iostream>`.

> ... same question for the standard library, when do you not need std::*?

`std` is the name of namespace containing classes in the standard library; it's there to avoid name collisions. Python has packages and modules to do this.

You can use the `using` statement to bring items from another namespace into your current scope, see [this FAQ entry](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/coding-standards.html#faq-27.5) for an example (and an explanation of why it's bad to blindly bring all of `std` into scope!).

> ... why is the "main" part a function? Do you ever call the main function? Why is it an integer? Why does C++ need to have a main function but Python doesn't?

Executable statements in C++ have to be contained within a function, and the `main` function is defined as where execution begins. In Python, executable statements can be placed at the top-level of a file, and execution is defined to .

You can call `main()` if you wish -- it's just a function, after all -- but there's not often a reason to do this. Behind the scenes, most implementations of C++ call `main()` for you once some startup housekeeping has been done by the runtime library.

The return value of `main()` is returned back to the operating system. This stems from C and UNIX, in which application programs are required to provide a 1-byte exit status code, and returning that value from `main()` is a clear way of expressing this.

> ... why do you need "std::cout << "? Isn't that needlessly long and complicated compared to Python?

This is just a design difference. iostreams is a fairly complex beast with lots of features, and one of the side-effects of this is that the syntax is a bit ugly for simple tasks at times.

> ... why do you need to return 0 even when you are never going to use it?

You do use it; this is the value returned to the operating system as the exit status of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Python is **high-level** language. C++ is **middle-level** language.

Comment: No, you don't always need iostream. Lots of graphical/windowed apps don't bother with console output.